# open editor/viewer for viewing realtime log - python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to create a function in my automation python code that will open an editor or other text viewer with the test log file while it's been written.
My automation is based on pytest so I am executing my tests with `pytest test_name.py` command.
I searched in the Internet and found that with `subprocess` python package I can do it but when I wrote the following code:

```
def __open_visual_logging(self):
    try:
        return subprocess.Popen(["vim",self._filename])
    except Exception:
        return None
```

Nothing is happening when I'm running my tests.
(The return value is 1)

Is there other way to do this (packages etc.) ? or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: and what you are trying to write in that file?

Comment: do you need something like the command `tail -F file_name.log` ?

Comment: You can try using `os.system('vim ' + self._filename)` instead. There is a space after vim before appending filename.

Comment: I am trying to view this log file while it been written (creating an interactive log viewer for yser).  I also tried the os.system option but it throws me an exception